# Access website on same docker container through Apache proxy container

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose

I have two Symfony web applications on my `php72-fpm` docker container, for accessing them, I use Apache httpd2.4 container

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
dfc5478e67af        httpd:2.4-alpine       "httpd-foreground"       58 minutes ago      Up 58 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   apache
959daf92b5a1        php:7.2-fpm            "docker-php-entrypoi…"   About an hour ago   Up 58 minutes       80/tcp, 9000/tcp                           php72-fpm
```

Now, when I am using them from my Frontend, everything works OK, but when I **try to access one website from another (from the backend), it doesn't work.**

[image: structure]

My `/etc/hosts` file

```
0.0.0.0         localhost
0.0.0.0         website1.local
0.0.0.0         website2.local
```

Part of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
php:
  container_name: php72-fpm
  image: php:7.2-fpm
  build:
    context: ./config/php
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ./website1:/var/www/html/website1
    - ./website2:/var/www/html/website2
  networks:
    - backend
apache:
  container_name: apache
  image: library/httpd:2.4-alpine
  restart: always
  build:
    context: ./config/apache/
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ./website1:/var/www/html/website1
    - ./website2:/var/www/html/website2
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  links:
    - php
  networks:
    - backend
```

website1.local VirtualHost file on Apache container

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website1.local
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/website1/public/$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website1/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/website1/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Example of error that I want to fix:

```
curl -I website1.local
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: website1.local
```

curl for getting website([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) or another container(apache) are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `website1.local` and `website2.local` in separate containers. It is the easiest and most configurable way. After that, you can access one container from another by their container name.